# TO_CHAR and IF stament in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g

I tried to store the day then use it in an if statement but it's not working....

it skip the if all

```
 select TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DAY')  into v_today from dual ; // save the day to v_today

  if v_today <> 'SUNDAY'  or  v_today <> 'SATURDAY'// check for the vlaue of v_today
  then
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('the office is open') ;
  else
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('the  office is close of the weekend') ; 
  end if;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you almost certainly want to use the format mask `fmDAY` rather than just `DAY`.  `DAY` always returns a 9 character string (assuming the session is set to use English).  If the day is anything other than Wednesday, it will be space-padded.  The `fmDAY` format mask removes the space padding.

Second, your IF condition is almost certainly incorrect.  If `v_today` is anything other than `NULL`, the `IF` condition will evaluate to `TRUE`.  If `v_today` was `SATURDAY`, for example, `v_today <> 'SUNDAY'` would evaluate to TRUE.  And since `TRUE or FALSE` evaluates to `TRUE`, the `IF` condition evaluates to `TRUE`.  I expect that you want either

```
IF( v_today IN ('SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY' ))
```

or

```
IF( v_today != 'SATURDAY' and v_today != 'SUNDAY' )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_1
IS
    v_today varchar2(20);
  BEGIN
     SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DAY') INTO v_today FROM DUAL;
        if (v_today NOT IN('SATURDAY','SUNDAY')) THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('the office is open') ;
        ELSE
               DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('the  office is close of the weekend') ;
 END IF;
 END;
```

execute this procedure
 SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
 EXECUTE P_1;